# Wrong format of ids! Google Analytics reader

Tags: google-analytics-api, gooddata

Does anybody have and idea on following problem? I'm downloading data from Google Analytics and see the following error:

> "errorClass":"com.gooddata.gcf.exception.TaskFailException","trace":"","message":"Worker task failed: Wrong format of ids!","component":"MSF",...

**`Return Code:`** 410 Gone

Cannot find anything.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please double check the PROFILE_ID attribute in the Google Analytics reader component. It is most probably set up incorrectly. You can use {PROFILE_ID} parameter and define the value in the workspace.prm file. The value of you Google Analytics Profile ID can be found when you open the reader component and click on the “…” three dots next to Profile ID field.

I hope this helped you!